# Определение количества дочерних элементов в родителе

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть кнопка, к которой нужно применить стили.

Стили, которые нужно применить для `button`, чтобы сделать отступ между текстом и иконкой:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

**Цель:**

- Если блок имеет 2 дочерних элемента — применить к нему стили.
- Если блок имеет 1 дочерний элемент или не имеет вообще,
  соответственно не применять эти стили

Хотелось бы сделать такую небольшую "операцию" на `CSS`.

**Мои попытки:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.button {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.35rem 1.6rem;
  background-color: hsl(214, 100%, 50%);
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: initial;
  font-family: "RobotoMedium";
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

.medium-btn {
  width: 13rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="button medium-btn" role="button">
  <span class="fw-medium fs-16 c-white">Continue</span>
  <div class="icon button-arrow">
    <svg width="36" height="20" viewBox="0 0 36 20" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none">
    <line x1="4" y1="10" x2="31" y2="10"/>
    <polyline points="26,7 31,10 26,13"/>
  </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.button {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.35rem 1.6rem;
  background-color: hsl(214, 100%, 50%);
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: initial;
  font-family: "RobotoMedium";
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}


.button > *:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.medium-btn {
  width: 13rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="button medium-btn" role="button">
  <span class="fw-medium fs-16 c-white">Continue</span>
  <div class="icon button-arrow">
    <svg width="36" height="20" viewBox="0 0 36 20" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none">
    <line x1="4" y1="10" x2="31" y2="10"/>
    <polyline points="26,7 31,10 26,13"/>
  </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="button medium-btn" role="button">
  <div class="icon button-arrow">
    <svg width="36" height="20" viewBox="0 0 36 20" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none">
    <line x1="4" y1="10" x2="31" y2="10"/>
    <polyline points="26,7 31,10 26,13"/>
  </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Неплохое уточнение

Comment: Изменил, теперь в ряд и отступы

Comment: В прочем сказать, такое решение для меня тоже не подходит, пробовал его буквально 10 минут назад. Я думал что есть какие-то решения с псевдоклассами. Типа `empty`, `only-of-type` etc. с комбинацией `:not()`.

Comment: Чем не подходит то? Вопрос уточните, тогда помогу, а так то сложно

Comment: `Три вещи, которые никогда не поймёт человечество: 1. Тёмная материя; 2. Источник гравитации; 3. Зачем ты раскодировал это сообщение=)`  --- оценил прикол)

Comment: Изменил, на псевдокласс, там проблема с выравниванием, если можно использовать флекс, то будет проще. Ну вообщем посмотрите

Comment: Хорошо, этого пока достаточно, в скором времени я добавлю ответ, если найду именно то решение, которое я искал, спасибо за помощь=)

Comment: попробуйте еще `last-child()` если Вам нужен не строго второй а последний элемент